# Why undeclared identifier error occurres while I'm using objet in class's function?

Tags: c++, oop, compiler-errors

I've been self teaching CPP OOP and this error occurred:
*Error  C2065   'carObj1': undeclared identifier*

And since I'm self teaching I tried to search on Internet but nothing found!
Can anyone help me with this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class car {
    public:
        string brand;
        string model;
        int year;
        void enterCar() {
            cout << "\nYour car is:" << carObj1.brand << " MODEL:" << carObj1.model << " BUILT-IN:" << carObj1.year;

        }
};

int main()
{
    car carObj1;

    cout << "Enter your car's brand name:\n";
    cin >> carObj1.brand;

    cout << "Enter your car's Model:\n";
    cin >> carObj1.model;

    cout << "Enter your car's Built-in year:\n";
    cin >> carObj1.year;

    carObj1.enterCar();



    return 0;

}
```

Comment: In the context of `car::enterCar`, there is no `carObj1` ; there is only `this` (which is implicit). Remove all the `carObj1.` from that function. Related, find the very best book you can. Trust me; that's mandetory.

Comment: https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/syntax-and-semantic-errors/
This is highly recommended site for beginners

Comment: @WhozCraig When we can not use it in our function so why should we use class object at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **problem** is that you're trying to access the fields `brand`, `model` and `year` on an object named `carObj1` which isn't there in the context of the member  function `car::enterObj`.

To **solve** this you can either remove the name `carObj1` so that the implicit `this` pointer can be used or you can explicitly use the `this` pointer as shown below:

```
void enterCar() {
//-------------------------------------------vvvvv-------------->equivalent to writing `this->brand`
            std::cout << "\nYour car is:" << brand <<std::endl;
//-----------------------------------vvvvvv------------------->explicitly use this pointer
            std::cout<< " MODEL:" << this->model << std::endl;
            std::cout<<" BUILT-IN:" << this->year;

        }
```

Also i would recommend learning C++ using a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: what is ```this``` ?

Comment: @EMVI `this` is a pointer. Refer to [this pointer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/this-pointer?view=msvc-170) and [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/this) for more details. It is also explained in any beginner level [c++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).